# Python isdigit if statement

Tags: python, arrays, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to setup a `for` loop in `main()` that checks if the user entered a number, a character or nothing. The output I want is `Invalid input` if they enter anything other than a number.

This chapter deals with arrays and I can't figure out how to get this done.

I've tried using `isdigit()` but I can't get it to work.

This is the main code I have setup which works fine:

```
def main():
    month_names = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',
                   'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
    total_rain = [0] * 12 # to store the total rain per month
    sum = 0

    for i in range(12):
        total_rain[i] = int(input("Enter the total rain in " + month_names[i] + ": "))
        sum += total_rain[i] #adding rain to sum
         #printing result
    print("\n\nTotal Rainfall: " + str(sum) + "\nAverage monthly rainfall: " + str(sum/12) + "\nLowest Rainfall: " + str(min (total_rain))
          + "In month of " +str(month_names[total_rain.index(min(total_rain))])+"\nHighest Rainfall: " + str(max(total_rain))+"In month of " +
    str(month_names[total_rain.index(max(total_rain))]))

main()
```

How can I get this done when using arrays? I've tried setting up a `for` loop like this:

```
   for total_rain[i] in i:
       if total_rain[i].isdigit():
           print("Invalid!")
           continue
       else:
           break
```

But that doesn't work.

Can anyone nudge me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `while` loop and check for a valid input.

Try this code:

```
def main():
    month_names = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',
                   'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
    total_rain = [0] * 12 # to store the total rain per month
    sum = 0

    for i in range(12):
        rain = None
        while not rain:  # while invalid input
            rain = input("Enter the total rain in " + month_names[i] + ": ")
            if not rain.isnumeric():  # not number
                print("Invalid!")
                rain = None  # retry input
        total_rain[i] = int(rain)
        sum += total_rain[i] #adding rain to sum
         #printing result
    s = "\n\nTotal Rainfall: " + str(sum) + "\nAverage monthly rainfall: " + str(sum/12) + "\nLowest Rainfall: " + str(min (total_rain))
          + " In month of " +str(month_names[total_rain.index(min(total_rain))])+"\nHighest Rainfall: " + str(max(total_rain))+" In month of " +
          str(month_names[total_rain.index(max(total_rain))])
    print(s)
    return s

main()
```

Output

```
Enter the total rain in January: asdfad
Invalid!
Enter the total rain in January: 
Invalid!
Enter the total rain in January: 12
Enter the total rain in February: 23
Enter the total rain in March: afad
Invalid!
Enter the total rain in March: 45
Enter the total rain in April: afcasdc
Invalid!
Enter the total rain in April: sc
Invalid!
```

Output 2

```
Enter the total rain in January: 1
Enter the total rain in February: 2
Enter the total rain in March: 3
Enter the total rain in April: 4
Enter the total rain in May: 5
Enter the total rain in June: 6
Enter the total rain in July: 7
Enter the total rain in August: 8
Enter the total rain in September: 9
Enter the total rain in October: 10
Enter the total rain in November: 11
Enter the total rain in December: 12


Total Rainfall: 78
Average monthly rainfall: 6.5
Lowest Rainfall: 1 In month of January
Highest Rainfall: 12 In month of December
```

Comment: I tweaked the code and ran a full test. The output looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

Get in a try..except block:

```
try:
  total_rain[i] = int(input("Enter the total rain in " + month_names[i] + ": "))
except ValueError:
  print("Invalid!")
```